# Why am I receiving a error with number of channels in U-Net

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, unet-neural-network

I am trying to implement U-Net following a tutorial, I have run into a problem with the number of expected input channels.

This is the error message that I get:

> RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 1, 3, 3], expected input[15, 3, 300, 300] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead.

This is my `double_conv` function:

```
def double_conv(in_c, out_c):
    conv = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_c, out_c,3,1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(out_c),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(out_c, out_c,3,1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(out_c),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

    )
    return conv
```

This is defining each of the down convolutions:

```
self.max_pool_2x2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
self.down_conv_1 = double_conv(1,64)
self.down_conv_2 = double_conv(64,128)
self.down_conv_3 = double_conv(128,256)
self.down_conv_4 = double_conv(256,512)
self.down_conv_5 = double_conv(512,1024)
```

This is my forward function:

```
def forward(self, image):
    #encoder
    x1 = self.down_conv_1(image)  #
    x2 = self.max_pool_2x2(x1)
    x3 = self.down_conv_2(x2)  #
    x4 = self.max_pool_2x2(x3)
    x5 = self.down_conv_3(x4)  #
    x6 = self.max_pool_2x2(x5)
    x7 = self.down_conv_4(x6)  #
    x8 = self.max_pool_2x2(x7)
    x9 = self.down_conv_5(x8)

    #decoder
    x = self.up_trans_1(x9)
    y = crop_img(x7, x)
    x = self.up_conv_1(torch.cat([x,y], 1))

    x = self.up_trans_2(x)
    y = crop_img(x5, x)
    x = self.up_conv_2(torch.cat([x,y], 1))

    x = self.up_trans_3(x)
    y = crop_img(x3, x)
    x = self.up_conv_3(torch.cat([x,y], 1))

    x = self.up_trans_4(x)
    y = crop_img(x1, x)
    x = self.up_conv_4(torch.cat([x,y], 1))

    x = self.out(x)
    return x
```

I initially thought it was a problem with changing the input channels for the 2nd Conv2d but this has not made any changes.

Full error backtrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rosha\Desktop\Final Year Project\Code\U-Net\train.py", line 148, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:\Users\rosha\Desktop\Final Year Project\Code\U-Net\train.py", line 113, in main
    check_accuracy(val_loader, model, device=DEVICE)

  File "C:\Users\rosha\Desktop\Final Year Project\Code\U-Net\utils.py", line 68, in check_accuracy
    preds = torch.sigmoid(model(x))

  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\rosha\Desktop\Final Year Project\Code\U-Net\model.py", line 76, in forward
    x1 = self.down_conv_1(image)  #

  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)

  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 204, in forward
    input = module(input)

  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)

  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 463, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)

  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 459, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 1, 3, 3], expected input[15, 3, 300, 300] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It's probably because you are giving your model a 3-channel input while it expects a single channel as input.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Ivan , i have changed the Image_channels to equal to 1 but i am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Could you provide the full error backtrace?

Comment: I have edited the original post to include it. Thank you @Ivan

Comment: When you input an image with three channels, what kind of error message / stack trace do you get?

Comment: `self.down_conv_1` should have 3 `channels_in` instead of just 1.